Authentication headers or use self signed cer with Azure Logic Apps?
I have an Azure Logic App which is triggered by HTTP request, I've noticed theres no real way to authenticate the app within Logic Apps unless I use SSO which I don't want.
Is there a way to implement simple username/password auth or even accept a signed request without using Azure API Management or Front Door (both cost options)?

Can you specify your requirement by sharing an example? @InvalidSyntax

Are you using this trigger? If yes, then you can use the Authentication by selecting the required authentication type

@IkhtesamAfrin The trigger from you screenshot polls an endpoint. The question seems to be about the Request trigger.

Thats right, this is for request triggers (inbound), not for outbound HTTP.

@IkhtesamAfrin Not sure what the example would include, I merely want to authenticate the inbound triggering HTTP endpoint without having to manually check the credentials from within the Azure App logic itself (which looks like what I'll have to do)

A very weird resolution, but can work if you just need to do some protection.

Add value in your request header for username and password.
Set a trigger condition to validate the incoming value of the username and password
If the value is incorrect, the app will not be triggered.
You can use the same by using a sort of API key which is passed and validated using trigger condition.

Expression:
@and(
    equals(triggerOutputs()?['headers']['username'], 'your_username'),
    equals(triggerOutputs()?['headers']['password'], 'your_password')
)

Addition Steps:


Testing:

Limitations:

To change password, you'll need to adjust the condition


Thank you for sharing, this would have been an ideal solution if we didn’t have to hardcode the passwords. We store and retrieve them from Azure vaults.
